# Adding custom function in callback parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I was trying to add function2 in my jquery hide method.I can do it through the code which is commented.So,can anyone please rectify my code.I want to call function2 from callback parameter of hide method.

```
<script>
//        $(document).ready(function () {
//            $("#p1").click(function () {
//                $("#p2").hide("slow", function () {
//                    alert("para2 is now hidden");
//                });
//            });
//        });

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p1").click(function () {
        $("#p2").hide("slow", function(){
            function2(); 
        });
    });

function function2() {
    alert("para2 is now hidden");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Now that I've properly indented your code, do you realise the problem?

Comment: What is wrong with this code it seems to be working just need to complete the $(document).ready() http://jsfiddle.net/8RvCs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you have a syntax error because you haven't closed your `$(document).ready()` function or method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p1").click(function () {
        $("#p2").hide("slow", function(){
            function2(); 
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/pmkD5/)

As already mentioned, you can just pass the function's reference if that is all that should be in the callback:

```
$("#p2").hide("slow", function2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you forgot to close the ready event handler,

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#p1").click(function () {
        $("#p2").hide("slow", function(){
            function2(); 
        });
    });
   });
```

And you can also try this code to improvise your code much better,

```
   $("#p1").click(function () {
     $("#p2").hide("slow", function2);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand, just pass the function that you want

```
 $("#p1").click(function () {
            $("#p2").hide("slow", function2);
    });
```